Expresiones RegeX en Python
Estoy siguiendo un proyecto de Noviembre 2022 y en el vídeo se usa la expresión de abajo para mostrar en parte lo que se ve en la foto.
En principio esa expresión debería mostrar todas las filas dónde hay (a.e.t.), (o al menos eso muestra en el vídeo), pero a mi me muestra las filas que no lo contiene y no he encontrado el pk.
Un ejemplo a continuación con lo que debería mostrarme el que me está dando problemas
import pandas as pd

data = {"Home" : ["team1", "tema2", "team3", "team4", "team5"],
    "Score" : ["2-1 (a.e.t.)", "0-3", "1-4 (a.e.t.)", "2-2", "3-0"],
    "Away" : ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"]
    }

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_df 
data_df[data_df["Score"].str.contains(r"[^\d-]", regex = True)]


Estas filas de la foto son las que debería mostrarme el DF con el que estoy trabajando, y no se pk no me las muestra. Los string que contienen los (a.e.t) tienen la misma estructura

Me parece que la expresión calza con cualquier cosa que no contenga un dígito o el signo "-". No veo donde aparece "a.e.t." en el código que das.

Como comenta Candid Moe, lo que hace ese filtro boleano es seleccionar todas las filas que en la cadena de la columna score tienen cualquier carácter que no sea un dígito (0-9) o el caracter "-", es decir "(a.e.t)", "41x", "12?", "foo", "-foo" o "28f" pasan el filtro, mientras que cosas como "41", "-32", "3" ó "---" no se incluyen.

Sería bueno que agregaras un [mcve] con un DataFrame de ejemplo y la salida esperada para aclarar el problema. Si quieres obtener las filas que contienen especificamente esa subcadena puedes usar algo como df_historic_data[df_historic_data["score"].str.contains(r"\(a.e.t\)")] o si quieres aquellas con esa cadena exacta, entonces
df_historic_data[df_historic_data["score"] == "(a.e.t)"].

Exacto, el objetivo de la expresión es mostrar las filas donde se encuentra la cadena de texto (a.e.t). En mi caso no me está funcionando y me está mostrando las otras filas, las que están correctas (2-1, 3-4 ...) La salida esperada es la de foto de arriba, que he tenido que hacer a mano, especificando literalmente lo que quería buscar.

@FJSevilla ya añadí un ejemplo mínimo

@BrianArmasQuintana, si no estoy pasando algo por alto, en principio la salida es la esperada, puedes comprobarlo online (es un intérprete normal, no Ipython pero es lo mismo, solo agrego un print): https://onlinegdb.com/R30LJvGdS  Supongo que usas IPython o Jupyter Notebook, el resultado debería ser igualemnte el esperado siempre que data_df[data_df["Score"].str.contains(r"[^\d-]", regex = True)] sea la última linea de la celda ejecutada para que se muestre.

Estoy usando jupyter notebook desde VSCode y sí, en este ejemplo si es la esperaba pero en el dataframe de los partidos de futbol que es con el que estoy trabajando no me muestra esa salida,  y es lo que no entiendo.

import pandas as pd

data = {"Home" : ["team1", "tema2", "team3", "team4", "team5"],
    "Score" : ["2-1 (a.e.t.)", "0-3", "1-4 (a.e.t.)", "2-2", "3-0"],
    "Away" : ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"]
    }

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data_df[data_df["Score"].str.contains(r"[^\d-]", regex = True)])

produce
    Home         Score Away
0  team1  2-1 (a.e.t.)   t1
2  team3  1-4 (a.e.t.)   t3

Process finished with exit code 0

Aparte de agregarle el print(), el código produce el resultado correcto que señalas.

Exacto en este caso si funciona, pero en el dataframe de los partidos de fútbol no, y es lo que no entiendo. En el vídeo si le funciona y no veo pk a mí no.

@BrianArmasQuintana. Entonces tu ejemplo mínimo está mal, pues no muestra el problema que quieres solucionar.
